# Generating REST documentation in a Codeigniter project

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter, rest, swagger-php

I have a REST webservice using Codeigniter and using this lib : https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

I want to generate documentation for this web service. I look to use Swagger UI to generate this documentation. But, I didn't find any documentation how to use Swagger with Codeigniter.

The only project using this two technologies is this one, but don't have a good documentation : https://github.com/panxp/codeigniter-swagger

Can someone paste an example using this two technologies or give me a link to a good documentation ?
Of course, if there is another good lib to generate documentation, I'll take it if it's usable with Codeigniter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In past projects I have used http://apidocjs.com/ which I find pretty easy to use and straightforward to generate from in multiple environments. It took me like 15-20 minutes to get going and looking how I wanted with it having npm already installed. This one doesn't really care about directory or code structure, just your supplied info in the doc blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use https://github.com/manish29ify/codeigniter3-restapi-with-swagger Still it is under development but you can use Swagger with PHP rest server very easily

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) are considered very low quality and [can get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.